# gulp - gulp-sass compiling from many directories

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

I am attempting to complile from two different directories and place the outputted files in the same place.

File structure:

```
- kit
`- scss
 `- kit.scss
 |- kit-flex.scss
 |- kit-grid.scss
 `- kit-reboot.scss

- default
 `- scss
  `- bootstrap.scss
  |- bootstrap-flex.scss
  |- bootstrap-grid.scss
  `- bootstrap-reboot.scss
```

Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('kit', function(){
  gulp.src(['**/scss/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/css'))
});
```

---

I am expecting all of the compiled files to be in the `css` directory... but they are not.

Expected:

```
- dist
 `- css
  `- bootstrap-flex.css
  |- bootstrap-grid.css
  |- bootstrap-reboot.css
  |- bootstrap.css
  |- kit-flex.css
  |- kit-grid.css
  |- kit-reboot.css
  `- kit.css
```

Actual output:

```
- dist
 `- css
  `- default
   `- scss
    `- bootstrap-flex.css
    |- bootstrap-grid.css
    |- bootstrap-reboot.css
    |- bootstrap.css

  `- kit
   `- scss
    `- kit-flex.css
    |- kit-grid.css
    |- kit-reboot.css
    |- kit.css
```

Any assistance on how I could achieve the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten) is what you're looking for.

```
var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');

gulp.task('kit', function(){
  gulp.src(['**/scss/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/css'))
});
```

Comment: Could you provide some code? I've tried it out and it doesn't seem to be working... although, that's probably because I don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: @JoshMurray I've updated my answer. Please let me know if you can get it to work or not and I'll do my best to help!

Comment: That's excellent! I was trying to create another task called `flatten` and run that when the `kit` task was finished. Works like a charm. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :D